# Compute the limit of $\frac{I [\left( 1-tR \right)^2+t^2I^2]^{n-1}}{\left( R-R^2t-I^2t \right)^n}$ as $t \rightarrow \pm \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, functions

Let $R$ and $I$ be two real numbers such that $I \neq 0$ and let $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

For each triple $(R,I,n) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^* \times \mathbb{N}$, let $f_{(R,I,n)}$ be a function of a (single) real variable $t$ defined as follows: $$f_{(R,I,n)}(t)=\frac{I [\left( 1-tR \right)^2+t^2I^2]^{n-1}}{\left( R-R^2t-I^2t \right)^n}.$$

Regardless of the domain of the function $f_{(R,I,n)}$, we are actually only interested in computing the following limitations: $$\lim_{t \rightarrow - \infty}f_{(R,I,n)}(t),$$ and $$\lim_{t \rightarrow + \infty}f_{(R,I,n)}(t).$$

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try factoring out as many copies of $t$ from the numerator and denominator as you can, and use the fact that $\lim_{t\to\pm\infty} 1/t^k = 0$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Comment: Please write the context of this problem and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's expand the terms of the numerator and denominator which are in parentheses. Then we shall pull out as many copies of $t$, as I mentioned in my comment:
$$
\begin{align}
f_{(R,I,n)}(t) & = \frac{I[1 - 2Rt + (R^2+I^2)t^2]^{n-1}}{[R - (R^2+I^2)t]^n} = \frac{I(t^2)^{n-1}\left[\frac1{t^2} - \frac{2R}t + (R^2+I^2)\right]^{n-1}}{t^n\left[\frac{R}t - (R^2+I^2)\right]^n} \\ 
& = t^{n-2}\cdot\frac{I\left[\frac1{t^2} - \frac{2R}t + (R^2+I^2)\right]^{n-1}}{\left[\frac{R}t - (R^2+I^2)\right]^n}
\end{align}.
$$
Now, the big fraction in the second term has a finite limit as $t\to\pm\infty$ because $\lim_{t\to\pm\infty} 1/t^k = 0$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, and the fraction is a rational function of $1/t$. We see
$$
\lim_{t\to\pm\infty} \frac{I\left[\frac1{t^2} - \frac{2R}t + (R^2+I^2)\right]^{n-1}}{\left[\frac{R}t - (R^2+I^2)\right]^n} = \frac{I(R^2+I^2)^{n-1}}{[-(R^2+I^2)]^n} = \frac{(-1)^nI}{R^2+I^2}.
$$
Therefore, the limiting behavior of $f_{(R,I,n)}(t)$ depends solely on that of $t^{n-2}$. Hopefully it is now clear that your desired limits are
$$
\lim_{t\to\pm\infty} f_{(R,I,n)}(t) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } n < 2\\
\frac{I}{R^2+I^2}& \text{if } n = 2\\
\pm\infty & \text{if } n > 2
\end{cases}.
$$
In particular, when $n > 2$, we have $t\to +\infty$ implies the limit is $+\infty$ if $n$ is even, and $-\infty$ if $n$ is odd. These cases are flipped when $t\to-\infty$.

Comment: Thank you so much